# Ant task failed on GWT compilation

Tags: java, gwt, ant, jenkins

I am using GWT 2.5.0, on gwt compilation, build failed occurs with Java returned: 137.

My environment is Jenkins build tool.

Here is my build code :

```
    <target
        name="clientcompile"
        depends="servercompile"
        description="GWT compile to JavaScript (production mode)" >

        <java
            classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler"
            failonerror="true"
            fork="true" >

            <classpath>

                <pathelement location="src" />

                <path refid="project.class.path" />

                <pathelement location="${gwt.sdk}\validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar" />

                <pathelement location="${gwt.sdk}\validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar" />
            </classpath>

            <jvmarg value="-Xmx512M" />

            <arg line="-war" />

            <arg value="war" />
            <arg line="${gwt.args}" />

            <arg value="com.skt.SKTWeb" />
        </java>
</target>
```

On running ant task i am getting this,

clientcompile:

[java] Compiling module com.skt.SKTWeb

[java]    Validating units:
 [java]       Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
 [java] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.

```
BUILD FAILED
/root/.jenkins/workspace/KINGSTRACK WEB APPLICATION/LTSWebEAR/build.xml:57: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/root/.jenkins/workspace/KINGSTRACK WEB APPLICATION/LTSWeb/build.xml:174: Java returned: 137
```

Why this error is occuring. My system is linux based system.

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried `ant -Dgwt.args=-strict` as suggested? (I'd suggest always using `-strict` BTW)